# How to run Xamarin Android app on web browser

Tags: android

I am trying to run my Xamarin android mobile app on browser by clicking on a hyperlink.

I added the required intent code above activity class.

When I click on hyperlink it says "cannot locate... "

Does the file with hyperlink have to be located in some particular folder?

Comment: Please provide your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
await Browser.OpenAsync(uri, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
```

If not, follow [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/open-a-web-link-using-default-browser-in-xamarin-forms-application-using-xamarin/) to detailed explanation.